# AccessViolationException when calling ExecuteReader of AseDataReader

Tags: ado.net, sap-ase

I get this error

> System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
>     HResult=-2147467261
>     Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>     Source=Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient
>     StackTrace:
>          at Sybase.Data.AseClient.Unmanaged.ModifyCommandTextForSchemaOnly(String commandText, StringBuilder modifiedCommandText, Int32 capacity)
>          at Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseCommand.ModifyCommandTextForSchemaOnly(String commandText)
>          at Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseCommand.GetCommandText(CommandBehavior commandBehavior)
>          at Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseCommand.SetCommandStatement(CommandBehavior commandBehavior)
>          at Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseCommand.Execute(CommandBehavior commandBehavior)
>          at Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseCommand._ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior commandBehavior)
>          at Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior commandBehavior)
>          at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior commandBehavior)

when calling

```
Dim cm As AseCommand = New AseCommand("SELECT * FROM Results;", cn)
Dim rd As AseDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly)
```

Where cn is an AseConnection.

I am using version 4.157.1000.0 of Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.dll

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the semicolon in the SQL text, remove it and all is well.

```
Dim cm As AseCommand = New AseCommand("SELECT * FROM Results", cn)
```